# Need to generate from and to numbers based on the result set with a specified interval

Tags: sql-server

I have below requirement.

Input is like as below.

```
Create table Numbers
(
    Num int
)
Insert into Numbers

values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15)

Create table FromTo
(
    FromNum int
    ,ToNum int
)

Select * From FromTo
```

Output should be as below.

```
FromNum ToNum
1       5
6       10
11      15
```

Actual Requirement is as below.

I need to load the data for a column into a table which will have thousands of records with different no's.
Consider like below.

1,2,5,7,9,11,15,34,56,78,98,123,453,765 etc..

I need to load these into other table which is having FROM and TO columns with the intervals of 5000. For example in the first 5000 if i have the no's till 3000, my 1st row should have FromNo as 1 and ToNum as 3000. second row: if the data is not having till 10000 and the next no started as 12312(This is the 2nd Row FromNum) the ToNum value should be +5000 i.e 17312. Here also if we don't have the no's data till 17312 it need to consider the ToNum between the 12312 and 17312

Output should be as below.

```
FromNum ToNum
1       3205
1095806 1100805
1100808 1105806
1105822 1110820
```

Can you guys please help me with the solution for the above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whta is the actual requirement?

Comment: Actual Req:I need to load the data for a column into a table which will have thousands of records with different no's. I need to load these into other table which is having FROM and TO columns with the intervals of 5000. For example in the first 5000 if i have the no's till 3000, my 1st row should have FromNo as 1 and ToNum as 3000. second row: if the data is not having till 10000 and the next no started as 12312(This is the 2nd Row FromNum) the ToNum value should be +5000 i.e 17312. Here also if we don't have the no's data till 17312 it need to consider the ToNum between the 12312 and 17312.

Comment: Sample output like as below.                                                                   FromNum ToNum
1 3205
1095806 1100805
1100808 1105806
1105822 1110820
1110825 1115820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may try in this situation is to group data and get the expected results:

```
DECLARE @interval int = 5

INSERT INTO FromTo (FromNum, ToNum)
SELECT MIN(Num) AS FromNum, MAX(Num) AS ToNum
FROM Numbers
GROUP BY (Num - 1) / @interval
```